# Using VBA in Excel to Google Search

Tags: vba, excel

Apologize me if my question is wrong. I have been attempting to use xmlHTTP object to google search and returns the hyperlink for the website of the first result in another cell in excel. I tested my VBA code for 100 rows,it works fine.

But I have a list of 150,000 records that I need to google search . If I attempt xmlHTTP object, Google think me spam ? Is it legit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a coding question, is it? http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run script batch by batch. Google usually blocks ips if particular ip hits Google frequently for same type of search !